# Option values are empty when using data-bind=with in knockoutJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am working on select input drop-down with knockoutJs but Option values are empty when using data-bind=with in knockoutJs. Can any one help me on this.

Dropdown.html

```
 <span class="price"><select data-bind="options: preferedTimeToPickup,optionsCaption: 'Dont Know or Does not Matter',
    optionsText: 'name',value: preferedTimeToPickupVal" id="u3413_input" ></select>
    </span>
```

Custom.js

```
    this.preferedTimeToPickup = 
    [{name:"Morning (8-11)",price:5},
     {name:"Lunch (11-2)",price:6},
     {name:"Afternoon (2-5)",price:7},
     {name:"Specific: 8:00",price:8.5},
     {name:"Specific: 9:00",price:9.5},
     {name:"Specific: 10:00",price:10.25},
     {name:"Specific: 11:00",price:11.25},
     {name:"Specific: 12:00",price:12.25},
     {name:"Specific: 1:00",price:13.25},
     {name:"Specific: 2:00",price:14.25},
     {name:"Specific: 3:00",price:15.25},
     {name:"Specific: 4:00 (closed at 4 on sat)",price:16.25}];

     this.preferedTimeToPickupVal = ko.observable();
```

Displaying data by using below html

```
<p data-bind="with: preferedTimeToPickupVal">
 <span data-bind="text: name"></span> 
</p>
<p data-bind="with: preferedTimeToPickupVal">
<span data-bind="text: price"></span>
</p>
```

Up to now everything is working fine, but in the select drop down `value=""` is empty, if i use `optionsValue: 'name'` in the `input type select`, then values are rendering fine but `data-bind="with: preferedTimeToPickupVal` is not working where i want to display the data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't rely on `document.getElementById('id').value` when using knockout. The `value` binding allows you to store more than just strings, which is pretty useful in your situation (since it supports the parts with the `with` binding). Good practice: link to your viewmodel if you need the `value` elsewhere. Bad practice: at least use `ko.dataFor(element).preferedTimeToPickupVal().price` to retreive the selected price from the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `optionsValue: price` and use `pureComputed` to get the right information based on the selected value.

```js
function viewModel () {
  var self = this;      
  self.preferedTimeToPickup = [
    {name:"Morning (8-11)",price:5},
    {name:"Lunch (11-2)",price:6},
    {name:"Afternoon (2-5)",price:7},
    {name:"Specific: 8:00",price:8.5},
    {name:"Specific: 9:00",price:9.5},
    {name:"Specific: 10:00",price:10.25},
    {name:"Specific: 11:00",price:11.25},
    {name:"Specific: 12:00",price:12.25},
    {name:"Specific: 1:00",price:13.25},
    {name:"Specific: 2:00",price:14.25},
    {name:"Specific: 3:00",price:15.25},
    {name:"Specific: 4:00 (closed at 4 on sat)",price:16.25}
  ];

  self.selectedPrice = ko.observable("");    

  // use this to get the selected value object and show it on the view
  self.preferedTimeToPickupVal = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    if(self.selectedPrice() !== "")
      return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.preferedTimeToPickup, function(time) {
        return self.selectedPrice() === time.price;
      });
    return null;
  }, this);  
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<span class="price">
  <select data-bind="options: preferedTimeToPickup,optionsCaption: 'Dont Know or Does not Matter',
optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'price', value: selectedPrice" id="u3413_input" ></select>
</span>

  <p data-bind="with: preferedTimeToPickupVal">
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>   
    </p>
  <p data-bind="with: preferedTimeToPickupVal">
    <span data-bind="text: price"></span>
  </p>
```

Comment: You **do not** need to wrap a `with` in an `if` binding. The `with` binding supports falsey values perfectly fine, it will just remove its contents. I appreciate you trying to help, but you might want to be a bit more careful with "maybe it's ..." in an answer :) If you can't find out what's wrong with the provided code, ask for clarifications in comments first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is working fine but the value="" is displaying empty in this example, i am facing same issue in my case. for some functionalities i need to render the value by "Id".

Comment: @M. Ihsan, The example is not displaying the proper values, please run the code snippet, am facing same output in my code also.

Comment: What do you want to put in the value? I put there the price.

Comment: Still i am facing "ReferenceError: price is not defined", the result's are displaying empty with unknown number as "Name: 9064848", am trying this code with requireJs in magento 2.

Comment: As the snippet is working great here, but in my code it is not working, please let me debug it, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

[Your code](https://jsfiddle.net/h2g3f5k6/1/) works fine, make sure you are using `this` correctly:

```
var vm = function () {
    this.preferedTimeToPickup = [{
        name: "Morning (8-11)",
        price: 5
      }
      //...
    ]

    this.preferedTimeToPickupVal = ko.observable()
}
ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

**Edit**

Ok, I think I understood what you want. Please see [my updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2g3f5k6/2/).

Basically, if you want to have the `value` attribute for every `option` node in your `select` tag, you have to use the `optionsValue: 'name'` option in the `option` binding.

By doing that, you are now storing the name property of the object, instead of the full object. You now have to find a way to fetch the correct object in your array, that match the selected value.

To do that, you could instroduce a temporary varialbe that hold your selection, and a computed observable that will filter the array when the selection change, and get the right object.

```
<span class="price"><select data-bind="options: preferedTimeToPickup,
    optionsCaption: 'Dont Know or Does not Matter',
    optionsValue: 'name',
    optionsText: 'name',
    value: _preferedTimeToPickupVal" id="u3413_input" ></select>
</span>

var vm = function () {
    this.preferedTimeToPickup = [ {}, {} ]
    this._preferedTimeToPickupVal = ko.observable();
    this.preferedTimeToPickupVal = ko.pureComputed(function() {
      var selectedVal = this._preferedTimeToPickupVal()
      var defaultVal = { price: null, name: null }
      var found = null
      if (selectedVal) {
        found = this.preferedTimeToPickup.filter(function(i) {
          return i.name === selectedVal
        })
      }
      return found && found[0] ? found[0] : defaultVal
    }, this)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is working fine but the value="" is displaying empty, i am facing same issue in my case. for some functionalities i need to render the value by "Id".

Comment: Knockout bypasses the `value` attribute since the selection is an actual object reference; not a string. If you use `optionsValue` it will work, but you need to re-compute your selection. Ultimately, having to access the `value` attribute through the DOM is a sign you're not following knockout architecture guidelines...

Comment: Ok, I think I understood what you want. You have to setup 2 things: a temp varialbe, that will store the value of the selection, and computed observable that will filter your array when the selection updates. See my update fiddle